# How to change placeholder for a disabled antd range picker component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

With the Antd library, you can set 2 placeholders and also disable 2 elements.

[image]

It seems that once disabled, the placeholder is not taken into account and sets the current date.

```
placeholder={["Start Date", "End Date"]}
disabled={[false, true]}
```

Comment: Can you show the entire `RangePicker` element? There is no such case to disable the placeholder in case of a disabled state. Also, will be good to mention the version of the library. Thanks